# How to lock dict key that is in progress

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have been working on a small "mini project" where I want to be able to "lock" a dict key that is in progress of generating values.

I have currently written:

```
import random
import threading
import time

test_dict = {}

random_proxies = [
    "http://test.io:12345",
    "http://test.io:123456",
    "http://test.io:1234567",
    "http://test.io:12345678"
]    

def random_challenge():
    print("LOCKING PROXY!!!")
    time.sleep(random.randint(5, 20))    

def do_proxies():
    while True:
        proxy = random.choice(random_proxies)

        # Mock data that it is hitting challenge / If a proxy is locked then retry with another proxy in the meanwhile
        if bool(random.getrandbits(1)):
            # Lock that proxy key for not being accessible to other threads
            random_challenge()    
            test_dict[proxy] = {
                "value1": "blabla",
                "valu2": "blablabla"
            }
            # Unlock the proxy to be accessible again

        print(test_dict)
        time.sleep(1)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(3):
        threading.Thread(target=do_proxies).start()
```

The idea of this script is that I will be running 3 threads all the time as you can see at the very beginning. What I am trying to do is that I want to continuously call the proxy variable and see if I dont get "hit by a challenge" which is the mock data of `if bool(random.getrandbits(1)):` if its true then its a challenge which will sleep for 5,20 seconds and here the problem is currently that it could happend that the same proxy could be hit at the same time the challenge

What I am trying to achieve is that if a proxy is in the challenge, no other threads should be able to access that proxy and should try to use another proxy if that proxy is already in a challenge. but I do not know how I can make a "lock" function for that and here I am,

my question is: How can I lock a specific proxy that is in a challenge and then unlock it when it is finished?

Comment: You can store a global dict with the current status of the proxy like `{'proxy_1': 'open'}`. If the status is locked, then in another thread, you can handle what to do if some proxy is locked.

Comment: this is just for mocking? in your do_proxies() call a function returning a dict of locked proxing before you do your `proxy = random.choice(random_proxies)` - if that one gets a value in your "blocked" dict you cannot access it - no need to make it multithreaded

Comment: @Epsi95 hmm, I could probably but hmm, I cant really get a grip on how I can implement it together to what I have created really, Either i'm morning tired or abit too stupid to understand, is it possible if you could do a small example maybe?

Comment: @PatrickArtner the reasaon of multithreading is that I want to continuously make threading work all the time so if a proxy is "in progress" then the thread should continue to use a new proxy while other threads are working on the "challenge" so that it will continuously work. I assume the returning a locked proxies is abit what Epsi95 mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea was simple, it is something like

```py
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time

list_op_proxy = ['proxy_1', 'proxy_2', 'proxy_3']
proxy_dict = dict(zip(list_op_proxy, ['available']*len(list_op_proxy)))

lock = Lock()

def handler(func):
    def wrapper(name, lock):
        global proxy_dict
        i=0
        while(True):
            each_proxy = list_op_proxy[i]
            lock.acquire()
            if(proxy_dict[each_proxy] == 'available'):
                proxy_dict[each_proxy] = 'busy'
                lock.release()
                print(f'acquired {each_proxy} by {name}')
                break
            else:
                lock.release()
            i += 1
            i %= len(list_op_proxy)

        func(name, lock)

        lock.acquire()
        proxy_dict[each_proxy] = 'available'
        lock.release()
        
    return wrapper

@handler
def process(name, lock):
    print('called', name)
    time.sleep(4)
    print(f'{name} finished')
    
Thread(target=process, args=('Thread 1',lock)).start()
Thread(target=process, args=('Thread 2',lock)).start()
Thread(target=process, args=('Thread 3',lock)).start()
Thread(target=process, args=('Thread 4',lock)).start()
Thread(target=process, args=('Thread 5',lock)).start()
```

```
calledcalled Thread 1
acquired proxy_1 by Thread 1
 Thread 2
acquired proxy_2 by Thread 2
called Thread 3
acquired proxy_3 by Thread 3
calledcalled Thread 5
 Thread 4
Thread 3 finished
Thread 1 finished
acquired proxy_3 by Thread 5Thread 2 finished

acquired proxy_2 by Thread 4
Thread 5 finishedThread 4 finished
```

Comment: Hi! Looks awesome! But is it actually necessary to use the "lock" if you are using available/busy to mark the proxy status ?

Comment: Hmm there is some stuff I dont understand, so you have two states of lock, one inside the while True and one outside, what is the reason of it if I might ask and why do we need to use global proxy_dict if we already have it at the top?

Comment: I think I should have acquired it before, consider the scenario, thread_1 found one proxy free, next step he wants to make it busy, but before going to next step, program is switched to thread_2, so thread_2 will also try to acquire it. Let me fix it.

Comment: You have to define global to tell that it's a global variable

Comment: now fixed, so when you are checking the state of proxy, you have the lock so that sudden thread switch won't happen.

Comment: I made something simple like this now just for the funs: https://hastebin.com/imuvumutak.py wouldn't this do the same thing like you did? I think the difference is that you use the next proxy in the list while I do a random right? also I removed the lock but is it possible that sudden thread switch could happend if I do it that way in the hastebin then?

Comment: yes, thread switch happens suddenly. So reading data is fine, but updating a variable, you should take care. Also random proxy does not guarantee no collision.

Comment: Don't think I fully get the grip of "thread switch", when do we call the thread switch? Yeah of course using random proxies doesnt guarantee but having the busy/available status should be fine, unless there is a huge chance that two threads still can acquire the same proxy?

Answer (score 1):

In case the amount of threads/proxies is not identical, you could shuffle first and take a proxy without saving its state:

```
import random
import threading
import time
from itertools import cycle


random_proxies = [
    "http://test.io:12345",
    "http://test.io:123456",
    "http://test.io:1234567",
    "http://test.io:12345678"
]    


lck = threading.Lock()
random.shuffle(random_proxies)
proxy_list = cycle(random_proxies)

def do_proxies(threadNum):
    lck.acquire()
    proxy = next(proxy_list)
    print(f"Thread {threadNum} got proxy: {proxy}")
    lck.release()
    time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    THREADS = 3
    for x in range(99):
        print(f"ROUND: {x+1}")
        threads = [threading.Thread(target=do_proxies, args=(i, )) for i in range(THREADS)]
        [t.start() for t in threads]
        [t.join() for t in threads]
```

Out:

```
ROUND: 1
Thread 0 got proxy: http://test.io:1234567
Thread 1 got proxy: http://test.io:12345
Thread 2 got proxy: http://test.io:123456
ROUND: 2
Thread 0 got proxy: http://test.io:12345678
Thread 1 got proxy: http://test.io:1234567
Thread 2 got proxy: http://test.io:12345
ROUND: 3
Thread 0 got proxy: http://test.io:123456
Thread 1 got proxy: http://test.io:12345678
Thread 2 got proxy: http://test.io:1234567
...
```

Comment: So the reason we dont collide the proxy here is taht you use next instead of random right? I mean if I would use random choice instead of `proxy = next(proxy_list)` then there is risk that two threads gets the same proxy, right?

Comment: Yes, `next` picks the next proxy, secured by `Lock` to make sure one thread at a time gets a proxy.