# How to lock using context manager

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have been trying to figure out context manager more and more and the more I am into it the more problem I seem to find. My current problem is that I have currently no lock which could cause that two or more threads could end up having the same shared value as I only want one value to be in used.

```
import random
import threading
import time

list_op_proxy = [
    "https://123.123.12.21:12345",
    "http://123.123.12.21:54321",
]

proxy_dict = dict(zip(list_op_proxy, ['available'] * len(list_op_proxy)))
proxy_dict['http://123.123.12.21:987532'] = "busy"


class AvailableProxies:
    def __enter__(self):
        while True:
            available = [att for att, value in proxy_dict.items() if "available" in value]
            if available:
                self.proxy = random.choice(available)
                proxy_dict[self.proxy] = "busy"
                return self.proxy
            else:
                continue

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        proxy_dict[self.proxy] = "available"


def handler(name):
    with AvailableProxies() as proxy:
        print(f"{name} | Proxy in use: {proxy}")
        # Adding 2 seconds as we want to see if it actually wait for the availability
        time.sleep(2)


for i in range(5):
    threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(f'Thread {i}',)).start()
```

as you can see in my context manager I want to random loop through a dict key:value that has the value set to available and if it is available then we set it to busy -> do some stuff and then exit it (release by settings the same value to available) - However my problem is that in rare cases it seems like more than 2 threads are able to get the same proxy which I want to block, I want only one thread to be able to access the context manager at the time so we can set the proxy value to busy so no other threads can take it.

How can I lock so only one thread can set the proxy to busy  so it doesnt happend that two or more threads set busy on the same proxy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lock dict key that is in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235046/how-to-lock-dict-key-that-is-in-progress)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Hi! It does not as it is locking the thread but not in the context manager. So it is missing the context manager. And btw, that was my thread too 

Comment: You seem to misunderstood locks. In Python locks do not protect any objects or resources, it only prevents thread execution.

Comment: @PéterLeéh Oh really? I was thinking as I am using the threads when executing the script. In that case I should be able to use the lock then, no? combined with context manager or am I swimming in the ocean now?

Comment: TBH the linked solution above looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to lock when looking for a proxy and release the lock after a proxy was found (usage is the same as in your previous question, no matter if you are using a context manager), I just added some more debug messages:

```
import random
import threading
import time

list_op_proxy = [
    "https://123.123.12.21:12345",
    "http://123.123.12.21:54321",
]

proxy_dict = dict(zip(list_op_proxy, ['available'] * len(list_op_proxy)))
proxy_dict['http://123.123.12.21:987532'] = "busy"
proxy_lock = threading.Lock()


class AvailableProxies:
    def __enter__(self):
        proxy_lock.acquire()
        self.proxy = None

        while not self.proxy:
            available = [
                att for att, value in proxy_dict.items() if "available" in value
            ]
            if available:
                print('%d proxies available' % len(available))
                self.proxy = random.choice(available)
                proxy_dict[self.proxy] = "busy"
                break
            else:
                print("Waiting ... not proxy available")
                time.sleep(.2)
                continue
        proxy_lock.release()
        return self.proxy

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        proxy_dict[self.proxy] = "available"


def handler(name):
    with AvailableProxies() as proxy:
        print(f"{name} | Proxy in use: {proxy}")
        # Adding 2 seconds as we want to see if it actually wait for the availability
        time.sleep(.1)


for j in range(5):
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=handler, args=(i, )) for i in range(3)]
    [t.start() for t in threads]
    [t.join() for t in threads]
    print("---")
```

Out:

```
2 proxies available
0 | Proxy in use: http://123.123.12.21:54321
1 proxies available
1 | Proxy in use: https://123.123.12.21:12345
Waiting ... not proxy available
2 proxies available
2 | Proxy in use: https://123.123.12.21:12345
---
2 proxies available
0 | Proxy in use: http://123.123.12.21:54321
1 proxies available
1 | Proxy in use: https://123.123.12.21:12345
Waiting ... not proxy available
2 proxies available
2 | Proxy in use: http://123.123.12.21:54321
---
2 proxies available
0 | Proxy in use: https://123.123.12.21:12345
1 proxies available
1 | Proxy in use: http://123.123.12.21:54321
Waiting ... not proxy available
2 proxies available
2 | Proxy in use: https://123.123.12.21:12345
---
2 proxies available
0 | Proxy in use: https://123.123.12.21:12345
1 proxies available
1 | Proxy in use: http://123.123.12.21:54321
Waiting ... not proxy available
2 proxies available
2 | Proxy in use: https://123.123.12.21:12345
---
2 proxies available
0 | Proxy in use: http://123.123.12.21:54321
1 proxies available
1 | Proxy in use: https://123.123.12.21:12345
Waiting ... not proxy available
2 proxies available
2 | Proxy in use: http://123.123.12.21:54321
---
```

Comment: Sorry for late resposne! Worked very well! Guess the only thing I had to do was to set the lock as you shown. Very good example! Much appreciated!